# Change global Authorization Filter attribute in a specified Action in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filter, authorization, action

All of my Actions has been registered a global Authorization Filter in config. But I want some specified Actions don't use the global Authorization Filter or need to change some filter attributes.

example:

```
the global filter:[new AA(){NeedLogin=ture}]

[new AA(){NeedLogin=false}]
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
  // go to log on page
  //............
}

Filter like this:

public bool NeedLogin{get;set;}
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) 
{
       //if this Action is not need login ,the return true directly. also don't check     usename        and password
if(!this.NeedLogin){
    return true;
}

//Check authorize  return true or false

}
```

Note:I think the "LogOn" Action has two same filters,one is "true" and one is "false".But I want to the "LogOn"'s "NeedLogin" is "false" only.

**Oh,my god this editor is so hard.**

Comment: Show the code of your custom authorization filter

Comment: public bool NeedLogin{get;set;}
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) 
{
 //if this Action is not need login ,the return true directly. also don't check usename and password
 if(!this.NeedLogin){
  return true;
 }

 //Check authorize  return true or false

}

Comment: Have you tried `[AA(NeedLogin=false)]`?

Comment: Maybe my mind is wrong.The Action should be added two "AA" filters.In fact I need change "NeedLogin" attribute to "false".After,I add a line code :"[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]" to the costom filter,so when I debug in filter core method ,the "IsNeedLogin" is "false". Maybe about filter's order?